# SQLite and Python bug

Tags: python, sqlite

Hey i use the following code :

```
            bookseats = [0,1]
        print"What seats would you like to book?"
        bookseats[0] = raw_input("Choice : ")
        bookseats[1] = raw_input("What is their user ID? : ")
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM seats WHERE Booked='N'")
        row = cur.fetchone()
        if row != None and row[2] == "S":
            booked = 'B'
            print "Seat Number:" , row[0] ,"Is now booked!"
            cur.execute("UPDATE seats SET CustID=? AND Booked=? WHERE Seat_name=? AND Day=?", (bookseats[1],booked,bookseats[0],choice)
```

But when i do this, the CustID Collumn just changes too 0 and the Booked collumn doesnt switch to 'B' Standing for Booking, it just sticks on 'N' Help me please ! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this query:

```
UPDATE seats SET CustID=? AND Booked=? WHERE Seat_name=? AND Day=?
```

You should use something like this:

```
UPDATE seats SET CustID=?, Booked=? WHERE Seat_name=? AND Day=?
```

Take a look here for more information about `UPDATE` queries: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp